# oracle subquery returns multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I am trying to identify a student's country of origin but the data is not clean. so i use a union to look in different places, but since data is not clean sometimes query returns 2 rows in subquery, how can i filter those 2 records based on a condition.

e.g.

```
select s.person_uid "Student ID", p.birth_date "DOB",
(
select decode(a.nation_desc,'Palestinian Territories','Gaza Strip','Great Britain','United Kingdom','Korea, Democratic People''s Rep','Democratic People''s Republic     of Korea','Bahamas','The Bahamas',
'Unknown Country','Unknown','Lao People''s Democratic Republ','Lao People''s Democratic Republic','Yugoslavia','Serbia','Afganistan','Afghanistan','Ireland, Republic of (Eire)','Ireland','Iran (Islamic Republic of)','Iran, Islamic Republic of','Holy See (City Vatican State)',
'Italy','Virgin Islands','British Virgin Islands','Saint Vincent and the Grenadin','Saint Vincent and the Grenadines','England','United Kingdom',null,'Unknown',a.nation_desc)
from address a
where a.address_type = 'MA'
and a.nation_desc is not null
and address_number = 1
and a.entity_uid = p.person_uid
union

select 'Canada' nation_desc from address
where address_number = 1
and address_type = 'MA'
and nation_desc is null
and state_province in     ('PE','BC','PQ','NS','QC','SK','NL','NU','AB','MB','NF','ON','NB','NT','YT')
and entity_uid = p.person_uid

union
select 'United States' nation_desc from address
where address_number = 1
and address_type = 'MA'
and nation_desc is null
and state_province in     ('CA','WI','MI','NM','MA','PA','UT','DC','WA','OK','NY','SC','IA','KS','FL','OH','MN')
and entity_uid = p.person_uid
) Country
from student s
left join person p on (s.person_uid = p.person_uid)
```

As I said in some cases it returns multiple rows for each student and both rows show different countries (bad data). All i want is one record per student, if there are multiple rows i need to look into another column to validate the actual country and thus take one row.

Comment: i have reduced the joins and columns to make the query readable. in actual it has many columns and table joins

Answer (score 0):

The right way to approach this problem is using an explicit join.  Your logic is a little hard to follow, because the query is rather complicated.  Try this:

```
select s.person_uid, p.birth_date,
       (case when a.Country = 'Unknown' and imputedCountry is not null then a.imputedCountry
             else a.Country
        end)
from student s join
     (select a.*,
             (case when  state_province in ('PE','BC','PQ','NS','QC','SK','NL','NU','AB','MB','NF','ON','NB','NT','YT')
                   then 'Canada'
                   when state_province in ('CA','WI','MI','NM','MA','PA','UT','DC','WA','OK','NY','SC','IA','KS','FL','OH','MN')
                   then 'United States'
              end) as imputedCountry,
             decode(a.nation_desc,'Palestinian Territories','Gaza Strip','Great Britain','United Kingdom','Korea, Democratic People''s Rep','Democratic People''s Republic     of Korea','Bahamas','The Bahamas',
'Unknown Country','Unknown','Lao People''s Democratic Republ','Lao People''s Democratic Republic','Yugoslavia','Serbia','Afganistan','Afghanistan','Ireland, Republic of (Eire)','Ireland','Iran (Islamic Republic of)','Iran, Islamic Republic of','Holy See (City Vatican State)',
'Italy','Virgin Islands','British Virgin Islands','Saint Vincent and the Grenadin','Saint Vincent and the Grenadines','England','United Kingdom',null,'Unknown',a.nation_desc
              ) as Country
      from address a
     )
     on a.address_number = 1 and a.address_type = 'MA' and
        a.entity_uid = PackageCFG.person_uid;
```

The idea is to impute a country from the postal codes and place that in `ImputedCountry`.  Then the country name itself is fixed in the subquery and put into `Country`.

The outer query chooses the `Country`, unless it is unknown and `ImputedCountry` has a value.